# Modificar color texto en función del valor de una variable en PHP

Tags: php, variables, color

Hola probando se me ocurrió la idea de intentar cambiar el color d e un texto en función del valor de una variable. La cosa paracía sencilla, pero no lo he conseguido. A ver si alguien me puede ayudar.

```
<?php
$valor= 1;

if ($valor == 1) {           
    $mostrar = "ROJO";       
}
else{
    $mostrar = "AZUL";
}
    echo $mostrar;

?>
```

Cómo puedo formatear el contenido de la variable $mostrar parfa que el texto me lo muestre en el color indicado. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Si usas Bootstrap puedes ir más allá que solo cambiar de color

```
<?php

    $result = 0;

    if ($result == 0) {
        $color = 'red';
    }
    else{
        $color = 'green';
    }

    if ($result == 0) {
        $alert = 'danger';
    }
    else{
        $alert = 'success';
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Parser</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Jquery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- CSS Styles -->
    <style>
        .color{
            color: <?php echo $color; ?>;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="color">
            El color de este texto cambiara en base al resultado !!!
        </p>

        <span class="alert alert-<?php echo $alert; ?>">
            El estilo de este texto cambiara en base al resultado !!!
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Resultados

[image: Success]

[image: Danger]

PD: El resultado 0 lo tomo como "malo o error" y el resto, sería lo que tu quieras, pueden ser 1 para "buenos", 2 para "informativos". En fin, tu imaginación es el limite. Te puedes guiar en los [Alerts de Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/alerts/) para ello.

Answer (score 0):

Quien renderiza el color, en todo caso es el cliente (navegador). Podrías usar estilos CSS de acuerdo al valor que tenga la variable, que yo llamaría `$color` y no `$mostrar`.

Un ejemplo muy sencillo, con estilos en línea:

```php
<?php
$valor = 2;
$color = $valor == 1 ? "red" : "blue";
echo '<div style="color: '.$color.'">Hola Mundo!</div>';
?>
```

Esto muestra la célebre frase "Hola Mundo!" en color azúl. He usado el [operador ternario](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) para decidir el valor que tendrá la variable `$color`.

Sin embargo, lo ideal es que uses estilos CSS en un fichero separado, y que decidas aplicar un estilo u otro dependiendo del valor de tu variable PHP.

Comment: yo lo veo incorrecto; es preferible trabajar con clases y eliminar esa dependencia de tocar el codigo html para determinar el comportamiento del fronten... si algo tiene que ser llamarivo: "warning", si algo tiene que ser informatibo "info" si algo debe ser excalamado como correcto: "success" semanticamente hablando ...

Comment: No veo por ninguna parte en la pregunta, que el usuario hable de "warning", "success" o "error". El usuario dice textaulmente: *se me ocurrió la idea de intentar cambiar el color d e un texto en función del valor de una variable*. Bajo esa premisa desarrollé mi respuesta. Eres libre de responder con lo que consideres sea la respuesta correcta y si mi respuesta te parece inútil, no válida o absurda también eres libre de votar negativo.

Comment: ya la respondieron: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/600379/315134